# how to convert pandas dataframe column addition to pyspark column addition

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to add a column based on existing columns in a pyspark dataframe.

I can add a column using pandas as

`transform_df = transform_df.withColumn('geohash', transform_df.apply(lambda x: pgh.encode(x.lat, x.lng, precision=9)))`

How can I add in spark? I used the following but have some errors where user defined function cannot have more than one arg:

```
    some_udf = F.udf(lambda x: pgh.encode(x.lat, x.lng, precision=9))
    transform_df = transform_df.withColumn('geohash',                                                
some_udf(F.col(transform_df['lat'], transform_df['lng'])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your UDF expects input from two different columns, your lambda function also needs to have two parameters:

```
some_udf = F.udf(lambda lat, lng: pgh.encode(lat, lng, precision=9))
#                       ^^^  ^^^   two parameters corresponding to two input columns below
transform_df = transform_df.withColumn('geohash', some_udf(transform_df['lat'], transform_df['lng']))
```